# Webbrick won't include the correct .css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following one of the best tutorials/books I have ever come across, the [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec%3acascading_style_sheets)
 but I am trying to include the "blueprint" stylesheets and assets/blueprint/screen.css returns this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
```

I have checked that the path to the file is correct:
    C:\triton2\public\stylesheets\blueprint\screen.css

And this is the top of my application.html.erb:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title><%= title %></title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen.css', :media => 'screen' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print.css',  :media => 'print' %>
    </head>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?  Better yet, how could I diagnose the proper solution on my own?  Nothing on the google is of use save [this which recommended a db:migrate](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-Action-Controller%3A-Exception-caught-p32852379.html) (didn't help)

[edit]
The solution was to put the style sheet in C:\triton2\public\assets\stylesheets\blueprint\screen.css 
and change application.html.erb to <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'stylesheets/blueprint/print.css',  :media => 'print' %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think it may need to be in the public/assets/stylesheets instead of just public/stylesheets if it is a rails 3.1 app.

Comment: You win the prize of A) being correct and B) my eternal love.  this is what I get for following a tutorial for Rails 3.0 with a Rails 3.1 install.